# How to read and modify the SSM parameter with python boto3

Tags: boto3, ssm

i am trying to develop a code where i can access and then modify and update the SSM parameter value .

Anyone , could you let me know how can this be achieved with boto3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

we can achieve modification by the following:

```py
response = ssm.put_parameter(
    Name='field_name',
    Value='new_value',
    Type='Type',
    Overwrite=True,
)
```

we can achieve read by the following

```py
response = ssm.get_parameters(
    Names=[
       'feild_name',
    ],
)
print(response['Parameters'][0]['Value'])
```

Answer (score 6):

You can read and write an already created parameter with this code:

```py
import boto3

ssm_client = boto3.client("ssm")

def get_parameter(name):
    parameter = ssm_client.get_parameter(Name=name)
    return parameter["Parameter"]["Value"]

def update_parameter(name, value):
    ssm_client.put_parameter(
        Name=name,
        Overwrite=True,
        Value=value,
    )
```

You can read the full documentation [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html)

Comment: `Overwrite=True` is missing "`,`" comma at the line end